# Can I transfer documents from the files app on iPhone to my new Android phone?

Tags: file-transfer, files, data-transfer, ios, samsung-smart-switch

I’ve already tried to use google drive to do so, but for some reason only empty folders get transferred. I’m switching to a Oneplus so the Galaxy Smart Switch app (which I had used to go iOS to Android once) is not compatible. I have a usb-c to lightning cable and have tried Wondershare MobileTrans which i guess no longer allows cable to cable transfer between ios and android? Please help it has been a week since my frustration.

Comment: search for oneplus migration app in google play

Comment: OnePlus Switch, I think you mean. It only transfers via iCloud and only some media that way.